# include時のパスの設定

Tags: php

include時のパスの設定時に絶対パス../hoge.phpではなく相対パスhttps://[IP address ]/user/test/post/hoge.phpをつかう場合があるのはなぜですか？ 絶対パスだけで済みませんか？

Comment: 絶対パスと相対パスの認識が逆だと思います。

Comment: そうですね 逆です